# orienting bone in edit mode to custom transform widget

Tags: python, armature, bones

I'm working on a project to animate origami. This requires aligning bones perpendicular to edge normals. My workflow is to create a custom widget from the edge normal and use that to orient a new bone. I snap the bone to a vertex and then the tail on each dimension until it is scaled to zero. I finally transform the tail on the dimension that is perpendicular to the edge. This is real tedious so I've written a script that adds a bone to a selected edge, but how do I orient the bone, either to the widget or perpendicular to the edge,  in python?

edit: For any others who pass this way,

```
        bpy.ops.armature.bone_primitive_add()
        b = arm.data.edit_bones[-1]  #last bone added
        b.select_head = True    #bone is added with tail selected, selecting head effectively selects the whole bone
        arm.data.edit_bones.active = b
        b.matrix = co.matrix.to_4x4()    #co.matrix is the orientation of the gizmo
        context_override = {'window': bpy.context.window, 'screen': bpy.context.screen, 'area' : area}
        bpy.ops.view3d.snap_selected_to_cursor(context_override, use_offset=False)
```

Comment: It not quite clear what you are asking here. An edge in 3D space doesn't have a unique normal direction (there are infinite directions perpendicular to an edge). Since you want to use use it for origami, you probably need a direction normal to the sheet of paper (which is a face which has an unique normal direction), am I right? Please explain your goals better and provide screenshots or a .blend file to show us what you mean

Comment: It is an edge of a face. Why would I attempt to rotate an edge on its own? The 'Normal' gizmo of the edge of a face in edit mode aligns along the edge in 'y', along the face normal in 'z', and perpendicular to the line in 'x'. A custom gizmo (widget) based on this allows me to orient newly added bones perpendicular to any edge. My solution is in the code snippet above.